# DB2 SQL query for a combination of conditions

Tags: sql-server, db2, where-clause

There is a table say `TABLEONE` with the following values:

```
COLA       COLB
----       ----
RED        LILY
RED        ROSE
RED        ORCHID
BLUE       LILY
PINK       LILY
PINK       ROSE 
PINK       ORCHID
PINK       LAVENDER
```

I have to incorporate a condition that says:

```
SELECT ALL FROM TABLEONE WHERE
COLA != RED AND
COLB != (ROSE,ORCHID) WHEN COLA = PINK
```

in DB2 SQL.

I tried various possible condition combinations such as below.

I end up losing VARIOUS values somehow if I use:

```
where (COLA != 'RED') AND
(COLB NOT IN ('ROSE','ORCHID') AND COLA = 'PINK')
```

I end up including `COLB: 'ROSE','ORCHID'` if I use:

```
where (COLA != 'RED') OR
(COLB NOT IN ('ROSE','ORCHID') AND COLA = 'PINK')
```

Can you please suggest any other way I can implement this apart from hard coding in my code to avoid `COLB: 'ROSE','ORCHID' if COLA = 'PINK'`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try a couple different ways.  Just using `not` is probably easiest:

```
Select * 
from TableOne
where ColA <> 'Red'
and not (ColA = 'Pink' 
         and ColB in ('Rose','Orchid')
        )
```

You can also implement this logic using `or`:

```
Select * 
from TableOne
where ColA <> 'Red'
and (ColA <> 'Pink' 
     or ColB not in ('Rose','Orchid')
    )
```

Edit: Here is the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f018/1/0.  It uses unions for display purposes (to show you that both queries return the same results), but you should only use one of the two options above.

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` operator can compare multi-column expressions, which can simplify the SQL predicates used for describing advanced filtering conditions:

```
WITH TableOne ( ColA, ColB ) AS ( 
   VALUES( 'RED', 'LILY' ),
    ( 'RED', 'ROSE' ),
    ( 'RED', 'ORCHID' ),
    ( 'BLUE', 'LILY' ),
    ( 'PINK', 'LILY' ),
    ( 'PINK', 'ROSE' ),
    ( 'PINK', 'ORCHID' ),
    ( 'PINK', 'LAVENDER' )
)
SELECT * FROM TableOne
WHERE ColA <> 'RED'
AND ( ColA, ColB ) NOT IN ( 
    VALUES( 'PINK', 'ROSE' ), ( 'PINK', 'ORCHID' )
);


COLA COLB
---- --------
BLUE LILY
PINK LILY
PINK LAVENDER

3 record(s) selected.
```